# Twitter Data: Is there a way to split based on a condition?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-mining, jupyter-lab

***Code Snip-It***

```
#Date Bool
def isDate(string):
    elem = []
    splits = string.split()
    for element in splits:
        elem.append(element)
    if len(elem) > 5:
        return True if elem[2].isdigit() else False
    else:
        return False

#LOAD HANDLER
def loader(file):
    lines = []
    with open(file,encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line)
    return lines

class define:
    def __init__(self, date, token, tweet):
            self.date = date
            self.token = token
            self.tweet = tweet
```

***Data Snip-It***

*Disclaimer: These tweets are public information. This is purely educational research that does not reflect on any image from this institution or it's people within*

```
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@WishYouWereMe__|RT @coriyonmarie: I’ll never forget how somebody did me.
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@c1Leonn|RT @nxlimaa: WHY am i incapable of doing natural makeup?????? why does everything always escalate ?????????
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@Oootentog|@staydilated13 Thank youuuu! ♥️
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@SushreeRonali|@GautamGambhir Jai Hind 
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@Tank9trACE|4 months old at that
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@mathewpoptartm|RT @Flashyasf: Aye be careful who you catch feelings for, Shit don't be real onna other side 
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@wakemeup0320|RT @NookNickn_r: Good night na~ ❤️ [LINK]
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@AkanniTheKing|@KiKardashiann We Got You 
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@nuggythebear|@MarcusRashford Sheryar is a strong Mancunian name. Heralds back to the Sheryars of the 1700's.
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@Iam_Adrii|RT @iRealPedro: PUBLIC @TANNEDja ANNOUNCEMENT 

The Road Marshall speaks ‼️⚠️‼️ [LINK]
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@blushkths|how much do i need to pay for jungkook to step on my neck
```

***Theory***

So my idea was splitting based on if the first elements of the line is the date and the function isdate() does this but I'm not sure how to append the previous element to the current so that the items would be joined? Not sure how understandable that was but ill try to illustrate it:

```
Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@Iam_Adrii|RT @iRealPedro: PUBLIC @TANNEDja ANNOUNCEMENT 

The Road Marshall speaks ‼️⚠️‼️ [LINK]
```

So in this snip-it, we see that the tweet has multiple lines and I need a way to join the two lines together so that I can do operations on it. So, if joined, this would look similarly to this:

```
['Tue Feb 04 12:36:05 EST 2020|@Iam_Adrii|RT @iRealPedro: PUBLIC @TANNEDja ANNOUNCEMENT The Road Marshall speaks ‼️⚠️‼️ [LINK]']
```

There's no \n or similar so I'm unsure how to proceed.
Eventually I will be putting this into a dictionary but I need to figure out the fundamentals first.

Comment: Don't _we see that the tweet has multiple lines_ and _There's no \n or similar_ contradict each other? Can you clarify things?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest first rewriting your function like this:

```
def isDate(string):
    splits = string.split(maxsplit=3)
    return len(splits) > 3 and splits[2].isdigit()
```

and then using it in this way:

```
def loader(file):
    lines = []
    with open(file,encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line_with_newline in f:
            line = line_with_newline.rstrip()
            if isDate(line):
                lines.append(line)
            else:
                lines[-1] += line
    return lines
```